# Irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ (ring $\mathbb{Z}$)

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

How to prove the irreduciblity over $\mathbb{Q}$ (ring $\mathbb{Z}$) of polynomials     $$f = (x-{a_1})\cdots(x-{a_n})-1$$ and $$g = (x-{a_1})^2\cdots(x-{a_n})^2+1,$$ {${a_i}$} - pairwise distinct integers.

Comment: @elektron Thank you. It still makes no sense to me...Do you want to prove irreducibility over $\;\Bbb Q\;$ , i.e. over the polynomial ring $\;\Bbb Q[x]\;$ , or over the polynomial ring $\;\Bbb Z[x]\;$, or what?

Comment: @Joanpemo sorry, I thought you don't understand because of latex syntax (from mobile version it don't convert). I think it 2 conditions of task (prove irreducible over Q, prove irreducible over Z)

Comment: @Elektron Thank you...that really was hard to understand! Then irreducibility over the integers is the same as over the rationals , by Gauss Theorem, so you only have to worry about what happens in one of the two polynomial rings.

Comment: @Joanpemo okay, thank you. So, i choose Q or Z polynomial ring...and what should I do next?

Comment: @Joanpemo thank you, but can you please explain this transition ${ h(a_1) = -k(a_i)-1}$?

Comment: @el It follows from the last equality in the first line. Check it carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose

$$f(x)=h(x)k(x)\;,\;\;h(x),k(x)\in\Bbb Z[x].\text{ But since }\;f(a_i)=-1=h(a_i)k(a_i)\;\;\text{we get}$$

$$ h(a_i)=-k(a_i)=\pm1\;,$$

for all $\;a_1,...,a_n\;$. But then $\;h(x)+k(x)\;$ is a polynomial of degree less than $\;n\;$ (otherwise the above decomposition of $\;f(x)\;$ is not a true one) which vanishes in $\;n\;$ different points , so

$$h(x)+k(x)\equiv0\implies h(x)=-k(x)\implies f(x)=-h(x)^2$$

but this last equality is impossible by comparing the coefficients of $\;x^n\;$ in both sides.

Now you try the other one.